# How to store and get data from JSON?

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to make a forums in Angular JS for which I want to make few JSON data files where I can store and get data from. Some of the problems to keep in mind.
I want to add new data from the browser not adding it to the data file directly. Thank you for the assistance

Comment: JSON is not a good storage medium for forum data. Get a database like mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just dealing with small amounts of data, JSON is fine, but if your datasets get large, definitely switch to a database like MongoDB or DynamoDb.

In the browser you can use `LocalStorage` to store your JSON payloads and you can access using a plugin like lawnchair:

http://brian.io/lawnchair/